# random forest/ boosting and overfitting issue

Tags: random-forest, boosting

I guess we can use CV to optimize how many trees (i.e. ntree or nround for boosting) in order to not overfit. It's like one of the way to not overfit.

If we have too many complex trees that we learned but do not use CV to get the optimal # of trees, the second way I can think of is to use early stopping for either random forest or boosting. So, there are two ways (i.e. running CV to get the optimal ntree or nround and use early stopping for both boosting or r.f.)

can you please check this? thx

Comment: You appear to have posted an answer to another question as a separate new question.

Comment: I think it's different because I am asking early stopping